# CLI: Frozen output after catching exception

Tags: php, command-line-interface

In my console scripts I use [My own ProgressBar class](https://github.com/Ex3v/PHP-ProgressBar) to display progress of batch process). Today, having below code:

```
$progressBar = new CliProgressBar(count($this->contracts));

foreach ($this->contracts as $contract) {
    echo $progressBar->drawCurrentProgress();

    try{
        $this->handleSingleContract($contract);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $this->ungeneratedContracts[] = $contract;
    }
}
```

something weird happened. When loop hits `Exception`, it is being catched, loop continues to run, but output is frozen until script ends (it then blows screen with lot of buffered data that should not be buffered, but displayed as they arrive). How to avoid this behavior? Can I somehow clean buffer after catching exception to make my output work again?

Comment: Why not moving the `echo` after the `handleSingleContract` call?